# SQL Query Trouble (with constraint)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a problem with a query I am running. I want to display the Empcode, Empname and postcode of all employees who satisfy the following: every stock item they sell has a price value above the average of all stock items.

So here is my query:

```
select distinct SU.empCode, SU.empName, SU.PostCode
from Suppliers SU, Stocks ST
where ST.Price >= (select AVG(Price) from Stocks ST)
```

I get all the employees back ( 6 in total ) but the correct answer is 2 employees.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: :How can you relate supplier table with stock table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
select empCode, empName, PostCode
  from (select SU.empCode, SU.empName, SU.PostCode, min(st.Price) over (partition by su.empcode) min_price,
               avg(st.price) over () avg_price
          from Suppliers SU, Stocks ST
         where SU.empcode = ST.empcode)
 where min_price > avg_price;
```

Comment: It really did work, however I found that using "select distinct" stopped the values from repeating, and it gave me the correct answer. Thank you DazzaL!